# Should I use Screen.PrimaryMonitor or Screen.AllScreens for setting Form.Location?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, screen

As the question suggestions, should I be checking the Rectangle to set a Form.Location (which is taken from a Settings file) based on:

**1.**

```
if (settings.X <  Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea...)
{
  // Set the form's Location based on the settings object
}
```

*or*

**2.**

```
int width = 0;
foreach (Screen screen in Screen.AllScreens)
{
    width += screen.WorkingArea.Width;
}

if (settings.X <  width...)
{
  // Set the form's Location based on the settings object
}
```

Or is there a simple one liner that does the task of #2? I'm working on dual monitors, but the user base may have any number of configurations.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want to do here - are you just trying to remember where the user last put the window, and you want to take into account multi monitors?

Comment: Yep just trying to persist the Location and Size. The 2nd method works but seems long winded

Comment: I think your second code sample is meant to say `if (settings.X <  width)`

Comment: Updated my source, it's a duplicate anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps my answer on this different question helps in this case too:

[Restoring Window Size/Position With Multiple Monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937298/restoring-window-size-position-with-multiple-monitors/940290#940290)

Comment: Looks like I have a duplicate