# Maximise form window in two screens C#

Tags: c#

I have a form which I wanted it maximized. It worked perfect with the below code, but when I moved the application to a computer with two screens only one screen was covered and the other not. I wonder if there is a way to make both screens have a full form?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

    }
```

Comment: Do you mean, the same Form, maximized in both screens? What if the screens have a different display area a size? What would be the size of the maximized Form? You could set the Form's Size to the combined size of the two Displays, remove the Borders... (but if the height of any of the two is different, the Dpi resolution is different...)

Comment: @Jimi in my case both screens are identical

Comment: I mean, what the System/Framework would do? Decide that a Form can be maximized only if two (or more?) Displays are exactly the same (what *the same* could mean)? And if the resolution of one of the Display changes while the Form is maximized, what happens then? Do we show a multi-resolution Form? Do we have that tech available?

Comment: @Jimi Yes, I want it maximised to the number of screens connected to the computer, if one screen then it will be maximized to one, if 2 then maximized to 2,...not sure what you mean by the resolution part

Comment: You can do something like this: `this.Location = new Point(0, 0); this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; this.Size = new Size(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue);`. If the left-most Display has coordinates `(0,0)` (some fine-tuning required if the Form has a StatusStrip). Otherwise, see how the VirtualScreen coordinates are defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103).

Comment: @Jimi And I place this `this.Location = new Point(0, 0); this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; this.Size = new Size(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue);` in Form1_Load, right?

Comment: As the last thing in the `Load` event or in the `Shown` event. Both would do. Set the `StartPosition` to something that is not `WindowsDefaultLocation` (in the Designer)

Comment: @Jimi What `StartPosition`? I thought to add this `this.Location = new Point(0, 0); this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; this.Size = new Size(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue);` in Form1_Load and that's it?

Comment: `StartPosition` is a property of the Form class. You can see it in the Properties panel in the Form's Designer. It controls pre-defined behaviors in relation to the Form starting position. You usually set it to `Manual` if you're setting the `Form.Location` directly.

Comment: @Jimi so Hanan’s answer should work, right?

Comment: It depends. Read the notes about [Displays disposition and VirtualScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103). Don't skip the part related to the application's DpiAwareness and, as already mentioned, the VirtualScreen's coordinates definition.

Comment: Previous answer here: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361211/maximize-form-on-both-screens-dual-screen-monitor

Answer (score 1):

Try this, assuming your screens are placed next to each other:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            Location = new Point(0, 0);
            var height = Screen.AllScreens.Max(x => x.WorkingArea.Height + x.WorkingArea.Y);
            var width = Screen.AllScreens.Max(x => x.WorkingArea.Width + x.WorkingArea.X);
            Size = new Size(width, height);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**WPF**

You can use an *Extension* method like this and call it from `OnLoaded`

```
 public static void MaximizeToSecondaryMonitor(this Window window)
        {
            var secondaryScreen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Where(s => !s.Primary).FirstOrDefault();

            if (secondaryScreen != null)
            {
                if (!window.IsLoaded)
                    window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;

                var workingArea = secondaryScreen.WorkingArea;
                window.Left = workingArea.Left;
                window.Top = workingArea.Top;
                window.Width = workingArea.Width;
                window.Height = workingArea.Height;
                // If window isn't loaded then maxmizing will result in the window displaying on the primary monitor
                if ( window.IsLoaded )
                    window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            }
        }
```

**WinForms**

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Bounds = GetSecondaryScreen().Bounds;
        this.SetBounds(this.Bounds.X , this.Bounds.Y, this.Bounds.Width, this.Bounds.Height);
 }

 private Screen GetSecondaryScreen()
 {
        foreach (Screen screen in Screen.AllScreens)
        {
            if (screen != Screen.PrimaryScreen)
                return screen;
        }
        return Screen.PrimaryScreen;
 }
```

Comment: There are many references mistakes, could you provide the references?

Comment: Are you using WPF or WinForms ?

Comment: I am using WinForms

Comment: @Tak, hello, just curious to know if the answer helped out, let me know thanks

Comment: I just tried it and it didn’t work, only one screen had the form

Comment: @Tak, just to clarify do you want to maximize form so it appears as one single form on both the windows ?

Comment: Yes exactly I want it expanded with the controls in it centered in the main screen

Comment: @Tak, I updated the answer, I've still been unable to test as I don't have an HDMI for the second monitor :)

Comment: Well, I should be able to try it out in the next couple days