# Dual Monitor Screen Capture issue

Tags: c#, multiple-monitors, system-information, monitors

I have dual monitors and I am working on a product that allows you to record your computer screen. Currently, I am using the following code:

Rectangle screenArea = Rectangle.Empty;
foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Screen screen in System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens){
screenArea = Rectangle.Union(screenArea, screen.Bounds);
}

Which inevitably (in my case) records the entirety of the desktop. With the aspect ratio of both screens, where "screenArea" is the area being recorded. Is there a way in which I can specify the active monitor in which the program is running on?

Thanks for any help,
Christopher.

Comment: Have a look at the `Screen` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but how do I know which one of these to use? The Primary Monitor Size Function is null...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help.

[How do I determine which monitor my .NET Windows Forms program is running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121600/how-do-i-determine-which-monitor-my-net-windows-forms-program-is-running-on)

Also, there is PrimaryScreen Property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.primaryscreen(v=vs.110).aspx

You can get an array of Screens that you have using this code.

```
Screen[] screens = Screen.AllScreens;
```

You can also figure out which screen you are on, by running this code (this is the windows form you are on)

```
Screen screen = Screen.FromControl(this); //this is the Form class
```

In short check out the Screen class and static helper methods, they might help you.

MSDN Link, doesn't have much..I suggest messing around in the code by yourself.

Comment: Alright, I have done a little bit of research and I have come up with this to record the entirety of the screen. It's just a case of trying to stop it from recording my second monitor...  // get entire desktop area size
                Rectangle screenArea = Rectangle.Empty;
                foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Screen screen in
                          System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens)
                {
                    screenArea = Rectangle.Union(screenArea, screen.Bounds);
                }