# How to determine on which monitor will my applications run? c#

Tags: c#

On my computer I have two monitors(regular one and usb elo display) and I wont my application only opens on usb display...any idea?

Comment: Is it Console, WinForms... application?

Comment: windows form application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [Screen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. It provides information about number of screens, which one is a primary screen etc. It also has the following method  [Screen.FromControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen(v=vs.110).aspx). It returns information about the screen that contains the largest part of the application. You can run it on the startup. If the method returns *usb display* then you should move the application to the second screen. See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121600/how-do-i-determine-which-monitor-my-net-windows-forms-program-is-running-on).

Here is an example that verifies if the current screen is the primary one. If not it finds it and changes the location of the application based on the bounds of the found primary screen. You can also use `DeviceName` to determine if the current screen is the correct one.

```
var current = Screen.FromControl(this);

if (!current.Primary) //you can also use device name e.g." s.DeviceName.Contains("...")
{
    var primary = Screen.AllScreens.Single(s => s.Primary);
    SetBounds(primary.Bounds.Left, primary.Bounds.Top, Width, Height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the rectangle of required monitor first:

```
Rectangle rect = Screen.AllScreens[n].WorkingArea; //n stands for the index of monitor you'd like to use
```

Then you should invoke the Windows API [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx) to move it via `Process.MainWindowHandle`.