# How do i implement this XML in my code?

Tags: c#, winforms, multiple-monitors

Here is a link to a question about restoring the window to its previous state...There is an xml file that I'm supposed to attach but i have no idea how. Can someone help me? Also, if I have a second form that I want to restore in its previous position do I have to place the code in that form as well?

[Restoring Window Size/Position With Multiple Monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937298/restoring-window-size-position-with-multiple-monitors)

Comment: _"There is an xml file that im supposed to attach but i have no idea how."_ Attach an XML file to your question, or in your code (the `settings.xml` file)?

Comment: the code for the xml file is in the link.

Answer (score 0):

The xml file presented is just the .NET application settings serialized, you just have to grab the provided code and use it without mind the xml content.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Project Properties, under Settings, you will see them there.